# Why should a variable be declared as static and final

Tags: java, static, final

A variable is declared as `static` to get the latest and single copy of its value; it means the value is going to be changed somewhere. But why should the same variable be declared as `final`, which will not allow the variable to be changed else where (constant value)?

Comment: I think you've got "static" confused with "volatile".

Comment: (Why do people upvote questions like this?)

Comment: @Stephen C: and if at least 3 people (including you) disagree with the upvotes: why did no one downvote it?

Answer (score 11):

`static` so that the variable or method can be accessed without creating a class instance, and there is only one variable for the class instead of one for each instance.

A `final` class cannot be extended. A `final` variable cannot have its value changed, it behaves as a constant. And a `final` method cannot be over-ridden.

Answer (score 3):

The minute a variable is defined as `final`, it should probably not be referred to as "variable", since it no longer "varies" :)

A `static` variable is not tied to any particular instance of a class -- it is only tied to the class itself and only from a scoping standpoint.

So there you are -- a `static` and `final` variable is actually a value that is not tied to any particular instance of class and does not vary. It is a constant value, to be referenced from anywhere in your Java code.

At some point, when you should decide to change the value of this constant, it only takes one change to propagate this change correctly to all other classes that use this constant.

Answer (score 2):

A variable declared as static means that its value is shared by all instances of this class. Declaring a variable as final gives a slightly better performance and makes your code better readable.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as "related to the type rather than to any instances of the type" - "shared by all instances" suggests that there has to be *at least one* instance, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

local `variables` are on the stack and are not static.

You can have a static `field` which may or may not be final.  You would make the field final if it is not going to change.

Answer (score 1):

`static final` is used in Java to express constants. Static is used to express class variables, so that there is no need to instantiate an object for that class in order to access that variable.

Final methods can't be overriden and final variables can only be initialised once.

If you only use the static keyword, that value will not be a constant as it can be initialised again.

Answer (score 1):

`static` fields can be modified (e.g. `public static` fields can be modified by any class). `static final` fields cannot be modified after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Static has nothing to do with getting the latest and single copy unless "single copy" here means one and the same value for all the instances of a class (however, I think you may be confusing it with `volatile`). Static means class variable. You make it final when you want that to be a constant (that's actually the way Java constants are declared: `static final`).

Comment: `static` is indeed about "single copy" and if you have two assignments to some field `o1.x = 0; o2.x = 1;` then unless the field is static, the later assignment may not be visible when reading `o1.x`. (Not saying the question makes sense, just saying that it's not certain that he is indeed mixing it up with volatile.)

Answer (score 1):

May be to provide something similar to `constants`.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mention yourself, this is done to create constants. You create a single field to hold a value with a specific meaning. This way you don't have to declare that value everywhere, but instead you can reference the static.

Answer (score 0):

Variables should be declared as `fields` only if they’re `required` for `use` in `more than one` method of the class or if the program should `save their values` between calls to the class’s methods.

for example `user.lastName` lastName should be field because it is `needed` during `object lifecycle`

Variables should be declared as `static` only if they’re `not` required for use in more than one method of the class or if the program should `not` save their values between calls to the class’s methods.

for example `Math.max(num1,num2)` Im `not intristed` in num1 and num2 `after compleating` this operation

Answer (score -1):

Final stops any classes inheriting from it

Comment: final `fields` can be accessible to sub-classes. public ones are accessing anywhere.

Comment: @Peter: Being final is orthogonal to accessibility.

Comment: Comment has nothing to do w/ question; furthermore `final` works like that only with non-private methods

Comment: @Jon, That is another way of putting it. I was trying to keep the terminology simple. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You create `static final` variable to make its value accessible without instantiating an object.
E.G.:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static final String endpoint= "http://localhost:8080/myClass":
     /* ...*/
}
```

Then you can access to the data using this line:

```
MyClass.endpoint
```

Comment: Wrong, that is what you use `static` for. `final` is neither here nor there

Comment: `final` is for constness. Without `final` anyone could change the value.

Comment: this statement is correct. However, your answer is misleading as it implies a connection between `static final` and the fact that a variable can be accessed without instantiating an object. The `final` keyword does not influence whether a variable can be accessed without instantiating an object, e.g. you can have a non-static `final` variable, which cannot be accessed without an insatnce of the class

Comment: That's true. My fault, I read the answer again and it's, like you've said, missing a clearer disinction between `final`, `static` and `static final`.